# Backtransform logdata, package and function doesnt work?

Tags: r

I'm trying to backtransform the data in the table. But I cant make it work. Does anyone know why? I want to backtransform the whole table but first I need to make the function work, therefor trying with one variable first.

```
trt <- c("A","B")
emmean <- c(0.95,0.23)
SE <- c(0.3,0.2)
df <- c(18.3, 24.6)
lower.CL <- c(0.60, 0.1)
upper.CL <- c(1.2, 0.5)

df <- data.frame(trt,emmean,SE,df,lower.CL,upper.CL)

library(confidence)
backtransform(df$emmean, type =  "log")

Error in backtransform(df$emmean, type = "log") : 
  could not find function "backtransform"
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.  Include what you tried *and* the output/errors it gives.

Comment: @Dason post is added

Comment: Did you have any errors after you ran library(confidence)?

Comment: @Dason  I have run library(confidence)  before the code, it cant find the function. Feel free to try! Does it work for you?

Comment: @user11916948 That's why I asked - did you see any messages after you ran library(confidence)?

Comment: Only the error i pasted in the post. Do you now any other package?

Comment: try: `confidence:::backtransform(df$emmean, type = "log")`

Comment: Yeah after installing the package it looks like the author failed to export that function in their NAMESPACE.

Comment: That and some others. Maybe they just forgot. But I would have thought CRAN prevents those types of misses during the checks.

Comment: @Edward - Not really. Actually going through the package code it looks like they really only did intend for a few functions to be exported.  I'm not sure why you would think CRAN prevents those types of issues when using internal functions that don't get exported is a very common thing to do in package development.

Comment: @user11916948 Was there something you read somewhere that made you think to use backtransform from this particular package?

Comment: @Dason I googled and found it. I'm not super experienced by r. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: I mean to undo a log you just use `exp`.  That's literally all the `backtransform` function here would do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type the following:

```
confidence:::backtransform(df$emmean, type = "log")
[1] 2.58571 1.25860
```

As mentioned by @Dason, the package authors did not export this function in their NAMESPACE making it somewhat hidden (non-visible).

Answer (score 1):

And you can as well use `exp(df$emmean)` instead. Actually, this basically what the `backtransform()` function does in your case.

Full code:

```
#' Back-transformations
#'  
#' Performs inverse log or logit transformations.
#'
#' @param x value to back-transform
#' @param type type of transform (log, logit).
#'
#' @return backtransformed value
backtransform <- 
function(x, type = c("identity", "log", "logit", "none", NA_character_)) {
    switch(
        match.arg(type),
        log = exp(x),
        logit = exp(x) / (1 + exp(x)),
        x
    )
}
```